# Swift. Firestore, get document by referenceID

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Im new in Firestore and not clear for me how i can the document by reference. For example

```
Users(collection):
Documents:
id: 123413 -> name: "test1", lastname: "test1"
id: we4321 -> name: "test2", lastname: "test2"
id: dsf234 -> name: "test3", lastname: "test3"
id: qwe124 -> name: "test4", lastname: "test4"
```

and for example new collection

```
Animals(collection):
Documents:
id: rewerwr -> name: "Dog1", ref: "/Documents/123413"
id: sad3432 -> name: "Dog2", ref: "/Documents/we4321"
id: q4324da -> name: "Dog3", ref: "/Documents/dsf234"
id: safdsf2 -> name: "Dog4", ref: "/Documents/qwe124"
```

How i can get for user `id: 123413 -> name: "test1", lastname: "test1"` animal `id: rewerwr -> name: "Dog1", ref: "/Documents/123413"`

For example getting user - `test1` will be like this

`Firestore.firestore().collection("Users").document("123413")`

But how i can get animal for this user?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest changing your `Animal` model a little bit to something like:

```swift
struct User: Codable, Identifiable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var name: String
    var lastName: String
}

struct Animal: Codable, Identifiable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var name: String
    var owner: User
}
```

This way when you retrieve an `Animal` document you'll have the owner information within that document itself. So:

```
animalDocumentReference.getDocument { docSnapshot, error in
    guard error == nil else { return }
    guard let animal = try? docSnapshot!.data(as: Animal.self) else { return }
    animal.owner  // You can now set this value to an @Published property or do whatever you want with it
}
```

You could also do this the other way around if that serves your purposes better. Have a property called `pets` in `User`.

```
userDocumentReference.getDocument { docSnapshot, error in
    guard error == nil else { return }
    guard let user = try? docSnapshot!.data(as: User.self) else { return }
    user.pets  // You can now set this value to an @Published property or do whatever you want with it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firestore can load data from a single collection at once as there are no joins available. If you want to display which animal belongs to which user you have to implement it inside your code.
You can refer the following article for [no sql data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/)